# Can't install VLC Ubuntu 14.04 because of dependency issues

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to install VLC on my Ubuntu server.  This is what I get when trying.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources
Ign http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports InRelease
Hit http://shell.ninthgate.se wheezy InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://shell.ninthgate.se wheezy/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://shell.ninthgate.se wheezy/main i386 Packages
Hit http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy/non-free i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Get:1 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ InRelease
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ InRelease
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Release.gpg
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
Get:2 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US
Ign http://shell.ninthgate.se wheezy/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://shell.ninthgate.se wheezy/main Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en
Get:3 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Ign http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Ign http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Ign http://ubuntu.mirror.frontiernet.net/ubuntu/ trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Ign http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Ign http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy/non-free Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Get:4 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Get:5 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main i386 Packages
Get:6 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Get:7 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Get:8 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US
Get:9 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Get:10 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US
Ign ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en_US
Get:11 ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en
Ign ftp://ftp.videolan.org ./ Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/happy-neko/ps3mediaserver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/happy-neko/ps3mediaserver/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/vanvugt/mediatomb/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/vanvugt/mediatomb/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done   
Some packages could not be installed.
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation
or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages
have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation: 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : 
   Depends: vlc-nox (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed 
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
   Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. –
```

Comment: Why are you using 12.04 mirrors in 14.04?

Comment: did not notice i was.  I had added this per one of the answers i found on here.                                                                                                            deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-security main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: Which one? Because you seem to have added 12.04 repositories over a dozen times. Remove all but one of the `precise` entries in your `sources.list`, replace `precise` (12.04) with `trusty` (14.04) in the one that you keep. Or post your `sources.list` here.

Comment: ok i did that now i am getting the following

Comment: larry@ubuntuserver3:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: Recommends: vlc-plugin-pulse (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: [Edit] your post to add more information, please. Also add you current `sources.list` and the output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: ok i reposted up top the info you asked for

Comment: Has anyone else noticed that there are Debian Wheezy repositories in this list? How does that work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, when you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've enabled **canonical partners** repository in file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

1. First take a backup of `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/sources.list.bk
   ```
2. open the file using any editor and **uncomment** the following line by removing **##** from the beginning:

   **`deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner`**

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> to search **canonical** and after uncommenting,

   <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>y</kbd> for save and exit.
3. Update the repository and install vlc:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install vlc -f
   ```

Actually some components are not available from native repository and it requires others repositories from other source say **Canonical Partners**. You can give it a try. Let me know for any issues or if you need any further clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-*
```

Comment: Tried that and got the following

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-fluidsynth : Depends: vlc-nox (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-jack : Depends: vlc-nox (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-libde265 : Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-notify : Depends: vlc-nox (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: vlc-plugin-pulse : Depends: vlc-nox (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-samba : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed                    Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0~pre1) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-sdl : Depends: vlc-nox but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-svg : Depends: vlc-nox (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
 vlc-plugin-zvbi : Depends: vlc-nox (= 1:2.0.6-dmo3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Same issue was discussed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957117/unmet-dependency-when-installing-vlc-on-ubuntu-14-04

Hope this time you will be able to fix the issue.